# Odd Monopoly situation: rolling doubles to get out of jail is ALSO third double in a row!

Tags: monopoly

I'm simulating Monopoly with a computer program and came across this situation:

- Roll: 4 + 4 = 8 (first double)
- Moved from "Tennessee Avenue" to "Atlantic Avenue".
- Roll: 2 + 2 = 4 (second double)
- Moved from "Atlantic Avenue" to "Go To Jail".
- JAILED!
- In jail!
- Roll: 6 + 6 = 12 (third double)
- FREED FROM JAIL!
- 3 DOUBLES!
- JAILED!

3 doubles were indeed rolled in a row, so the poor fella was jailed once again. I'm assuming this is not how it should be though.... how should this work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per the [official rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/00009.pdf), "[y]our turn ends when you are sent to jail". So in that situation, having landed on the "Go To Jail" space, the player gets put in jail and his turn ends so he has no opportunity to roll the third time.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Time to add `doublesInARow = 0;` to the jail function!

Comment: Perhaps the question was a bit easier than I thought... I am only simulating one player, so I haven't programmed "beginnings" or "ends" of turns.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of simulating a single-player game of Monopoly?

Comment: @murgatroid99 Probabilities of landing on each space, probably? I don't think the other players can do anything to cause you to move differently.

Comment: While that is almost always correct, technically another player can minutely affect those probabilities (by choice) by choosing whether to hold or use a Get Out of Jail Free card. That affects the probabilities of getting certain movement cards from Community Chest, which in turn cascades out to subtly affect the probabilities across the board. That choice can also affect your probability of getting that card and having the opportunity to leave jail earlier.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Aha, good point! Suuuper small, but nonzero!

Comment: On the other hand, I'm pretty sure that's the *only* way for any player to affect any other player's movement by choice.

Comment: Yes. I also can't simulate very well the user's choice to pay their way out before the third turn so it makes little difference.

Comment: All these factors could be simulated. "Go To Jail" could be treated as a separate probability space ("once someone plays Go To Jail", reset the probabilities and use this chart instead"), and then you calculate the probability of Go To Jail at any point in the game.

The thing that really busts the whole thing apart is that [official (aka non-tedious) Monopoly uses the Auction Rules](http://monopoly.wikia.com/wiki/Official_Rules), and that completely screws up what "landing on a space" means.